# Repeater objects appearing on all detail views - django

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have two models with a foreign key, one to many relationship so that I can get a repeater model (images) in the admin. The image repeater works fine, my problem is that the images for the field - video_stills saved on  one of the film post/objects repeats across all film posts.

Here is my code:

model.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models
from embed_video.fields import EmbedVideoField
from sorl.thumbnail import ImageField

class Timestamp(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

# Film Model
class Film(Timestamp):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    order = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0, blank=False, null=False)
    meta_description = models.TextField('Meta Description', max_length=170, 
        help_text='Content for description meta tag - Max 170 Characters')
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='thumb')
    video = EmbedVideoField(blank=True)
    director = models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True)
    cinematographer = models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True)
    producer = models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True)

    publish = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    date_published = models.DateTimeField()

    # thumb for admin
    def image_thumb(self):
        return '<img src="%s" height="200" width="300"/>' % (self.image.url)
    image_thumb.short_description = 'Image'
    image_thumb.allow_tags = True

    # override the admin name + add ordering
    class Meta(object):
        ordering = ('order',)
        verbose_name_plural = "Film Projects"

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

    # helper method
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return "/film/%s/" % self.slug

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super(Film, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

# Film Stills Image Model
class FilmStillsImage(models.Model):
    video_stills = models.FileField(upload_to = 'images')
    film = models.ForeignKey(Film)

    class Meta(object):
        verbose_name_plural = "Film Stills"
```

views.py

```
# film single
def film_detail(request, slug):

    film = get_object_or_404(Film, slug=slug)

    # get all repeater images
    film_grabs = FilmStillsImage.objects.all()

    try:
        next_film = film.get_next_by_date_published()
    except Film.DoesNotExist:
        next_film = None

    try:
        previous_film = film.get_previous_by_date_published()
    except Film.DoesNotExist:
        previous_film = None

    return render(request, 'film/film_detail.html', {
        'film': film,
        'film_grabs': film_grabs,
        'next_film': next_film,
        'previous_film': previous_film
    })
```

film_detail.html

```
            <div class="section project-stills">
                {% if film_grabs %}
                <div class="row">
                        {% for filmstillsimage in film_grabs %}
                        <div class="grid-item four">
                            {% thumbnail filmstillsimage.video_stills "600x338" crop="center" as im %}
                                <img src="{{ im.url }}">
                            {% endthumbnail %}
                        </div>
                        {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:4 %}
                     </div>
                 <div class="row">
                    {% endif %}
                        {% endfor %}
                 </div>
                {% else %}
                    <p>Nothing found.</p>
                {% endif %}
            </div>
```

admin.py

```
class FilmStillsImageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass

class FilmStillsImageInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = FilmStillsImage
    max_num = 8
    extra = 0

class FilmAdmin(SortableAdminMixin, admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Film
    list_display = ('title', 'meta_description', 'image_thumb', 'video', 'director', 'cinematographer', 'producer', )

    inlines = [FilmStillsImageInline]

    prepopulated_fields = {'slug': ('title',)}
```

I'm sure its a simple fix, I have a feeling its because of objects.all() in my views, populating it to each item.

Apologies if its a stupid question and thanks for any help!!

Comment: This isn't clear, I'm afraid. *Where* are the film images repeating?

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. The images for the associated field 'video_stills' are appearing on every film item or post (detail view), even though they weren't saved on each item. I hope that makes sense!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing all film grabs to the detail template, so naturally they'll all display. Instead of doing that, you should just follow the reverse relationship in the template to show the ones that are actually related:

FilmStillsImage

```
<div class="section project-stills">
      <div class="row">
          {% for filmstillsimage in film.filmstillsimage_set.all %}
               ....
```

and there is no need to pass film_grabs from the view at all.

Comment: Thank you so much Daniel, really appreciate it, legend!! Just another question, is my approach the best way to get images to repeat upload in the admin? Cheers again!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "repeat upload", but this is the standard way to have a one-to-many relationship.

Comment: I meant multiple image upload via the admin using the one-to-many relationship. I'm new to django and coming for WP they have the Advanced Custom Fields plugin to provide this functionality...